# Mismatch Url from Url.Content

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Through Ajax I am trying to hit action method (city) of controller (Home) using below code

```
 url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/city")',
```

from the address bar I found that the Url is mismatched as I am in different controller. For example if I am in site controller then it is redirecting to site/Home/city. In place of this it should redirect to Home/city. Means its taking the current controller and the url which I am passing through Url.Content.
If I place javascript code in .aspx then the Url getting redirect correctly, if the javascript code is in separate file it raising the above mentioned issue.
How to redirect to particular Url from javascript?

Comment: You cant use `@Url.Content` or any razor code in an external javascript file (its not parsed by the view engine)

Comment: Why are you using `Url.Content` to get the path to an action link in the first place? You should be using `Url.Action`.

Answer (score 3):

If your JavaScript is in an external file you can use the following technique to access the route path to your action.

Simply attach the url to the element which invokes the ajax call as a data attribute.

In the below example I attach it to an input button.

```
<input data-url="@Url.Action("city", "Home")" value="DoPost" />
```

Then from within your event handler you can use jQuery `data` method to read the attribute i.e.

```
var superUrl = $(this).data('url');
```

Then use this in your ajax call:

```
url: superUrl
```